# Table View resizing issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

I am developing an app that will have a small login screen. I used a table view that calls separate nib files. Each nib file is set to have a 100 row height and the entire table (3 rows) has a a height of 300. It seems to not work well depending on the size of the iPhone. In the following screenshot you can see there is still white space added after the last row. How could i adjust the table view as a whole to be the same size as all 3 of the table view cells? I could adjust it so it works for this one iPhone screen but it will not look good for others. I am using swift to code if that helps.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by getting the Iphone models screen size and divide in to / 3. You use like this in the view controller :-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = self.view.frame.height / 3
}
```